# Как проверить является ли аргумент строкой или числом?

Tags: c++, строки, перегрузка-операторов

Есть шаблонный класс, мне нужно перегрузить оператор "-".

```
template <class type>
....
void operator -(type d)
{
   ???
}
```

К примеру, если `(type == string)`, то выполняются одни операции, а если `(type ==int,float,char)`, то другие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вам необходимо специфицировать шаблон для string.

```
template <> Class<string>
....
void operator -(string d)
{
   ???
}
```

Для числовых типов может использоваться общий шаблон:

```
template <class type> Class
....
void operator -(type d)
{
   ???
}
```

Если просто проверить тип, то можно использвать [std::is_arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) и определить является ли параметр числом.

```
if (std::is_arithmetic<type>::value)
{
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

Если вы используете C++11 или старше. В ином случае можно попробовать [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

```
if (typeid(string) == typeid(type))
```

Comment: И при этом .size() в случае строки не сработает

Comment: Тогда вам необходимо специфицировать шаблон для string. Тогда он будет использовать только для них, а общее определение будет использовать для чисел.

Comment: Что за ерунда со String?

Comment: @int3, специализация шаблона. А правка твоя какая-то сомнительная.

Comment: @int3, вот похожий пример на вашу проблему: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c401y1kb.aspx

Comment: @Qwertiy, не заметил, что шаблонный класс, а не метод. Я предлагал полиморфизм - для строки конкретный оператор (не специализация шаблона), для остального шаблонный. До правки там вообще был template <class String>, что специализацией точно не является.

Comment: @Unick, вопрос не мой, если что

Answer (score 1):

Дополню соседний ответ для потомков. Включаем c++17 и с радостью пишем

```
template <class T>
void operator -(T v) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>{}) {
        size_t len = v.length();
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>{}) {
        // Работаем, как с числом
    }
    else {
        static_assert(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr`, конечно, хорошо, но вот для встроенных типов перегрузка всё равно работать не будет.

Comment: @alexout, так это как оператор внутри класса, я так понимаю. Там все будет работать. Глобальный, конечно, не перегрузить

Comment: Согласен. Упустил этот момент.